# draw from skew normal distribution using stan

Tags: r, normal-distribution, stan

Is there a way to draw from a skew normal distribution in stan ? If not, is there a way to draw from a normal distribution and then transform to skew normal ?

**UPDATE**

I found `y~skew_normal(mu, sigma, alpha)` in the stan manual, but when I sample for instance 1000 values with parameters

`mu=1,
  sigma=10,
  alpha=-1000`

I also get some `-inf` values. Any ideas why ?

**UPDATE 2**

My `testing.stan`

```
data{
  real mu;
  real sigma;
  real alpha;
}
model{

}
generated quantities{
  real temp;

    temp = skew_normal_rng( mu,  sigma,  alpha);

}
```

and then my `testing.R` file

```
sdata <- list(
  mu=1,
  sigma=10,
  alpha=-1000
)

 model <- stan_model("stan code//testing.stan")

system.time(
  samples  <- sampling(model,data=sdata,seed=42,
                       chain=1,algorithm="Fixed_param",
                       iter=10000,thin=1,control=list(max_treedepth=9)
  ) 
)

object <- rstan::extract(samples)
# hist(object$temp,breaks=100)
# plot(density(object$temp))
# mean(is.finite(object$temp))
# sum(!is.finite(object$temp))
sort(object$temp)
```

And after running `sort(object$temp)` i get some `-inf` values.

Comment: If you just want random draws, use `skew_normal_rng` in the `generated quantities` block. If your question is actually "How can I estimate the parameters of a data-generating process that is assumed to be skew-normal?" then you need to use the `skew_normal` sampling statement or `skew_normal_lpdf` function.

Comment: @BenGoodrich i updated the question

Comment: OK. That is a bug then.

Comment: I verified it's a bug and filed an issue:  https://github.com/stan-dev/math/issues/527

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running this model:

`parameters {
  real y;
}
model {
  y ~ skew_normal(1, 10, -1000);
}`

I don't get infinite draws.  I do get a whole lot of divergences, though, which means the numerics are unstable.  That's true even if I lower the initial step size and increase the target acceptance rate.

With a skew parameter of -10 instead of -1000, that problem goes away.

There may be ways to change the internal implementation for more stability for extreme skew values, but it's definitely numerically problematic with -1000.

Comment: This problem also occurred with skew parameter -4